# Htaccess 301 redirection without category and subcategory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

How to redirect my site from domain.pl/category/post and domain.pl/category/subcategory/post to domain.pl/post?
For example:
Now is:
http://yonelle.pl/zabiegi/oferta/zabiegi-na-twarz/urzadzenia-i-technologie/mezo-odmladzanie-mezorollerem-dmn-mikronakluwanie/
I want redirect to
http://yonelle.pl/zabiegi/mezo-odmladzanie-mezorollerem-dmn-mikronakluwanie/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rule on top of your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} yonelle\.pl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(zabiegi)/.+?/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$2 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Unfortunetly I checked it and doesn't work. 
I want to redirect only URLs with string: 
"http://yonelle.pl/zabiegi/". 
For example: 
http://yonelle.pl/zabiegi/xxx/post, 
http://yonelle.pl/zabiegi/xxx/yyy/post 
to http://yonelle.pl/zabiegi/post